# Finding all edges within a certain distance in a graph containing loops in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph, priority-queue

I have a graph of `Node` objects connected by `Edge` objects that needs to be explored in the following way:

I am given a starting `Edge source` and need to find all other `Edge` objects so that the sum of lengths of passed edges along the path is no longer than `MAX_RANGE` as well as perform some operation at each `Edge` that meets the condition.

My solution to this problem is to recursively branch out, keeping track of travelled distance as I go (`Edge#getEdgeConnections()` returns an `ArrayList<Edge>` containing all `Edge` objects that connect to the `Edge` it's called upon) :

```
private final ArrayList<Edge> occupiedEdges = new ArrayList<>();

private void doStuffWithinRangeOf(Edge source) {
    doStuffAtEdge(source);
    for (Edge connection : source.getEdgeConnections()) {
        doStuffAtBranch(connection, source, 0);
    }
}

private void doStuffAtBranch(Edge edge, Edge source, double distance) {
    double newDistance = distance + edge.getLength();
    doStuffAtEdge(edge);
    for (Edge connection : edge.getEdgeConnections()) {
        if (!connection.equals(source) 
                && !isOccupied(connection) 
                && (newDistance < MAX_AP_RANGE)) {
            doStuffAtBranch(connection, edge, newDistance);
        }
    }
}

private void duStuffAtEdge(Edge edge) {
    occupiedEdges.add(edge);
    ... // Some amount of work that mustn't be done more than once per Edge
}

private boolean isOccupied(Edge edge) {
    return occupiedEdges.contains(edge);
}
```

Now, this should work fine, except for one thing - the graph contains several cases of loops.

As such, if the recursive algorithm starts with the longer path around the loop, some edges that are within the specified range when choosing the shorter path may be missed, as shown below

```
  ----------- C ---- D - E    // The algorithm explores AB, BC, CD and makes them occupied
  |           |
  B           |               // DE is too far along this path, and isn't occupied
  |           |
  ------------A               // When the algorithm explores along AC, it finds that CD 
                              // is already occupied and stops
                              // even though DE is really within range
```

Now, the solution I thought of was to do a different search pattern, where I would have a list (or map) of "frontier" edges, and explore them in order of increasing distance (adding new edges to this frontier every time an edge was explored).

There may be a large amount of edges involved, so I'd rather not loop through the whole list every time to find the one the shortest distance away from the source.

Is there some type of collection that automatically keeps an order in this fashion and is efficient in adding/removing elements?

Is SortedMap what I'm looking for? How would I use it in this case?

**Edit:**
Thanks to all responders. I ended up using a `PriorityQueue` with a wrapper class (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31336645/4719659) for details and code).

Comment: Instead of using isOccupied() logic, why don't you store the full path and check if a specific path has already been checked before?

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would mean that `doStuffOnEdge()` could be called several times for a single `Edge` if it was reachable by several different paths, something I wouldn't want. An alternative there would be to use both the path and `isOccupied()`, and keep exploring without calling `doStuffOnEdge()` on occupied edges. That may work, but I'd rather not explore the same edges more than once.

Comment: when you say `sum of lengths of passed edges along the path is no longer than MAX_RANGE ` is it simply the edge count or it's a weighted graph?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using some other datastructure, i would suggest adapting your algorithm:

You have implemented some sort of [depth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to go through your graph. If you use some kind of [breadth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) instead, you can just stop when you reach the specified range and have visited every edge within range exactly once (by using the isOccupied logic you already implemented).

Comment: With that I would still visit some edges twice (correct?)(since range isn't the amount of steps in the graph but the sum of lengths of edges along the path), but only call the `doStuffOnEdge()` once per Edge. Interesting.

Comment: well you can adapt the breadth first search of course to not visit any edges, that you visited before (usually you check for nodes). In your case i would even suggest to do this, since the first time you visit an edge with breadth-first-search will always be one of the shortest possible paths to this edge.

Comment: Well, only shortest in amount of steps though, right? Imagine there were 10 more nodes between A and C in my example. A-B-C would be a shorter route as far as Breadth First would be concerned.

Comment: yes of course, you did not mention any weights for the edges, so i assumed you are counting steps :) ("weight" is the term you use if you want to evaluate different values - for example the length - of the edges). Either way it is possible to include weights in the bread-first-search as well of course, if you need it!

Comment: Sorry, it's in the code, but didn't mention it in text... Will update to clarify. Anyway, I'll look into weighted breadth first. Thanks! Temporarily solved the first problem by putting `if (isOccupied())` around the `doStuffAtEdge()` method instead of the `doStuffAtBranch()`.

Comment: @HW no, you are not guaranteed that the first time that you visit the edge you will do so by the shortest path - even if you order edges before visiting them. You are attempting to write Dijkstra as BFS, which only works if all edges have the same length. On the other hand, BFS with a priority queue is Dijkstra, and it works (and never visits edges twice).

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm that you are looking for is a modified [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), where instead of search for the shortest path from A to B, you are searching for all shortest-paths shorter than X. Dijkstra guarantees that you will visit each node in increasing order of distance from the start, and through the shortest path from the start. Additionally, if there are no negative-length edges, then parenthood will never change -- and you are guaranteed that the inner `if` will be executed once and only once with each edge along a minimal path to a node. However, since the set of "nodes closer than X" is only known at the end (= those with final distance < max), you could wait until the algorithm finishes to `doStuffAtBranch` only for branches that actually lead somewhere interesting.

The pseudocode would go as follows:

```
final HashMap<Node, Double> distances = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Node, Node> parents = new HashMap<>();
distances.put(start, 0);  // start is at distance 0 from start

PriorityQueue<Vertex> q = new PriorityQueue(allVertices.size(), 
    new Comparator<Vertex>() {
        public int compare(Vertex a, Vertex b) {
            return distances.get(a) - distances.get(b);
        }
});

for (Vertex v : allVertices) {
    q.add(v, distances.contains(v) ? 
        distances.get(v) : Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
}

while ( ! q.isEmpty()) {
    Vertex u = q.poll(); // extract closest
    double current = distances.get(u);
    if (current > max) {
        // all nodes that are reachable in < max have been found
        break;
    }
    for (Edge e : u.getEdges()) {
        Vertex v = u.getNeighbor(e);
        double alt = current + e.length();
        if (alt < distances.get(v)) {
            q.remove(v);       // remove before updating distance
            distances.put(v, alt);
            parents.put(v, u); // v will now be reached via u
            q.add(v);          // re-add with updated distance
            // if there are no negative-weight edges, e will never be re-visited
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar to this, but using a wrapper class implementing the `Comparable` interface. Interesting to see your solution though.

Comment: If that was the only difference, then my pseudo-code is better than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

After a few iterations, I ended up using a solution similar [to that of user tucuxi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31321901/4719659). I used a `PriorityQueue` with a wrapper class implementing the `Comparable` interface. As I realised I needed to explore the graph in several different cases and do different things, I made a general use method in the `Edge` class that returns all other edges within a provided range.

**Code:**

```
public ArrayList<Edge> uniqueEdgesWithinRange(double range) {
    ArrayList<Edge> edgeList = new ArrayList<>();
    PriorityQueue<ComparableEdge> frontier = new PriorityQueue<>();
    frontier.add(new ComparableEdge(0.0, this));

    while(!frontier.isEmpty()) {
        ComparableEdge cEdge = frontier.poll();

        edgeList.add(cEdge.edge);

        if (cEdge.distance < range) {
            for (Edge connection : cEdge.edge.getEdgeConnections()) {
                if (!edgeList.contains(connection)) {
                    frontier.add(new ComparableEdge(cEdge.distance + connection.getLength(), connection));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return edgeList;
}

private class ComparableEdge implements Comparable<ComparableEdge> {
    private double distance; // Distance from closest point on source to furthest point on edge
    private Edge edge;

    private ComparableEdge(double distance, Edge edge) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.edge = edge;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableEdge another) {
        return Double.compare(distance, another.distance);
    }
}
```

The amount of indentation in the method makes me feel abit iffy, so I'll probably refactor it abit, but otherwise it should be functionally complete.

Answer (score 1):

This Java implementation uses DFS, the graph represented as Adjacency Matrix. Also uses an int array for processed nodes as well as one for marking distance of a node from the startNode

```
public List<Integer> findMinDistantNodesUsingBF(int[][] graph, int startNode, int distance) {
    int len = graph.length;
    boolean[] processed = new boolean[len];
    int[] distanceArr = new int[len];
    LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    queue.add(startNode);
    processed[startNode] = true;
    distanceArr[startNode] = 0;
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int node = queue.remove();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (graph[node][i] == 1 && !processed[i]) {
                if (distanceArr[node] == distance - 1) {
                    result.add(i);
                } else {
                    queue.add(i);
                    distanceArr[i] = distanceArr[node] + 1;
                }
                processed[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modification of either BFS or DFS, where you also add an extra rule for the MAX_LENGTH of the path (besides checking whether you have visited all of the neighbor nodes).

I would suggest that you went for DFS as it is a bit close to what you are doing at the moment. You can also easily "put in" the doSomethingToEdge in either method

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: After writing the answer, I realised that you are talking in terms of edges, but same example and same theory I mentioned in terms of Nodes will also work with edges.**

If you do simply BFS, it's not going to work, because you will mark a `node` as visited prematurely. Consider this example

Your max_range is 20 & `d(x,y)` represents edge weight between `x` and `y`

```
         A->(10)E->D(10)->(5)F // d(A,E)=d(E,D)=10 & d(D,F)=5

         A->(5)B->(5)C->(5)D->(5)F //d(A,B)=d(B,C)=d(C,D)=d(D,F)=5
```

In a situation like this, You would reach D in the path `(A-> E-> D)` first (since it is closer to A in this path) and you would mark `D` as visited. Which is actually wrong, because marking D as visited stops you from visiting `F`, which you could have done, if your path was `(A->B->C->D->F)`.

So to avoid repetitions and also solve this problem, with each node you are adding you should also add `List of nodes` that you have seen in the **current path**. This way you can still visit `F`, because when you reach `D` in the path `(A->B->C->D)` you will see it as unvisited because it did not occur in your path.

Coming to implementation, I will give you a rough idea:

create a wrapper class

```
   NodeWrapper{
      Node node;
      List<Node> Parents;
      int pathSum;
   }
```

Your BFS should look like this :

```
 { 

   Queue<NodeWrapper> queue = new LinkedList<>();
   Queue.add(new NodeWrapper(sourceNode,new ArrayList<Node>));

   while(!queue.isEmpty()){
         NodeWrapper temp = queue.poll();
         Node presentNode = temp.getNode();
         List<Node> parentsList = temp.getParentsList();
         for all neighbours of presentNode
              if neighbour is not in presentNode && (pathSum +currentEdgeWeight )< max && your conditions
             add currentNode to parent list
             queue.add(new NodeWrapper(neighbour,parentList,(pathSum +currentEdgeWeight)));

   }

 }
```

Comment: BFS is a bad idea for this, and using linked lists to record all possible paths potentially wastes a lot of memory. Imagine a 2d square grid of size 100x100 - how many different paths are there from one edge to the other?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Finds all nodes that are maximum x distance away from given node.
public Set<Integer> findMaxDistantNodesRecurse(int[][] graph, int startNode, int distance) {
    int len = graph.length;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (startNode == j)
            continue;
        if (graph[startNode][j] == 1) {
            set.add(j);
            if (distance > 1)
                set.addAll(findMaxDistantNodesRecurse(graph, j, distance - 1));

        }
    }

    return set;
}
```